# Maven project dependent on Ant project

Tags: java, maven, ant, dependencies

Our main project is "common-core", an Ant project. This codebase is under constant development.

We have another project "batch" which is a Maven project. In this project we would like to use the "common-core" as a dependency.

I've tried doing something like this in the pom file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>mydomain</groupId>
  <artifactId>ibcore-with-dependencies</artifactId>
  <version>current</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${project.basedir}/../common-core/bin/common-core-with-dependencies.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
...
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>validate</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <configuration>
          <tasks>
            <touch file="${project.basedir}/../common-core/bin/common-core-with-dependencies.jar" mkdirs="true" />
          </tasks>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>clean</id>
        <phase>clean</phase>
        <configuration>
          <tasks>
            <exec dir="${project.basedir}/../common-core/build" executable="ant" failonerror="true">
              <arg line="clean" />
            </exec>
          </tasks>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>build</id>
        <phase>process-resources</phase>
        <configuration>
          <tasks>
            <exec dir="${project.basedir}/../common-core/build" executable="ant" failonerror="true">
              <arg line="single-jar" />
            </exec>
            <copy todir="${project.build.directory}/lib" 
               file="${project.basedir}/../common-core/bin/common-core-with-dependencies.jar" />
          </tasks>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

But this doesn't work as the validation step fails if the `common-core-with-dependencies.jar` doesn't exist before the build starts. That is, the `touch` command happens too late.

The ant task in the `process-resources` phase builds common-core and creates an all-in-one jar with common-core plus its dependencies.

Is there a way to have the validate step not fail because of the missing common-core-dependencies.jar or to execute an ant step before `validate`?

I have a work-around to wrap the mvn build command within a script that executes `touch` on the `common-core-with-dependencies.jar` but I'm hoping to avoid that.

---

**Edit:**

I got something working using the information linked to by Blaine's answer but it still ended up being quite complicated.

`common-core` has a lib directory containing build and test dependencies. These may not be the same versions that Maven would choose but they are known to work so that is what I want.

I added two new Ant targets into `common-core` (for build and test-build) that creates super-jar files containing the content of all the dependent jars (or test-jars).

Unfortunately, a number of things go wrong with this:

- Some of the jars were signed. I have to strip the signing files from META-INF
- The various spring jars all contain the same META-INF/spring.* files.  These need to be combined. I struggled to get Ant to deal with these duplicate names but got it going with a bit of a hack in the end.

Ant target code:

```
<target name="single-jar" depends="build"  
        description="Produce a single jar containing core-common plus all its dependencies for use by batch">

    <jar destfile="${core-depends.jar}-temp" filesetmanifest="merge">
        <fileset file="${core.jar}" includes="**/*.class"/>
        <fileset dir="${core.src}" includes="**/*.properties" />
        <zipgroupfileset dir="${core.lib}">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
            <exclude name="notdeployed/**/*.jar" />
        </zipgroupfileset>
    </jar>

    <!-- The combined jar file contains multiple instances of various spring.* files.
         Many of these need to be concatenated into a single instance.
         The only way I can think of to do this is to extract them with distinct names
         before concatenating them -->

    <delete dir="${core.bin}/spring" quiet="true"/>
    <unzip src="${core-depends.jar}-temp" dest="${core.bin}/spring">
      <patternset>
        <include name="META-INF/spring.*"/>
      </patternset>

        <scriptmapper language="javascript">
          self.addMappedName(source + '.' + (Math.random()));
        </scriptmapper>
    </unzip>
    <mkdir dir="${core.bin}/spring"/> <!-- In case there was nothing to unzip -->

    <concat destfile="${core.bin}/spring.schemas" fixlastline="true">
        <fileset dir="${core.bin}/spring" includes="META-INF/spring.schemas.*" />
    </concat>

    <concat destfile="${core.bin}/spring.factories" fixlastline="true">
        <fileset dir="${core.bin}/spring" includes="META-INF/spring.factories.*" />
    </concat>

    <concat destfile="${core.bin}/spring.handlers" fixlastline="true">
        <fileset dir="${core.bin}/spring" includes="META-INF/spring.handlers.*" />
    </concat>

    <concat destfile="${core.bin}/spring.tooling" fixlastline="true">
        <fileset dir="${core.bin}/spring" includes="META-INF/spring.tooling.*" />
    </concat>

    <jar destfile="${core-depends.jar}">
        <zipfileset dir="${core.bin}" prefix="META-INF/" includes="spring.*" />
        <zipfileset src="${core-depends.jar}-temp" excludes="META-INF/spring.schemas META-INF/spring.handlers META-INF/spring.factories META-INF/spring.tooling META-INF/**/*.SF, META-INF/**/*.DSA, META-INF/**/*.RSA"/>
    </jar>

    <delete dir="${core.bin}/spring" quiet="true"/>
    <delete file="${core-depends.jar}-temp" />
    <delete quiet="true">
        <fileset dir="${core.bin}" includes="spring.*"/>
    </delete>

</target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to build a project AND reference it in the same pom. Instead, try  creating a new pom that is dedicated specifically for the ant build. Then reference that project in this one as a dependency.

Here is an article that provides a very good explanation of this process: https://web.archive.org/web/20140227062842/http://devblog.virtage.com/2013/04/embed-and-run-ant-tasks-and-scripts-from-maven/

Comment: I managed to solve this using the link you provided plus a lot of experimentation.

Comment: The link is broken, which makes this answer not very useful any more in this point in time.